# PHPUnit needs an absolute path to phpunit.xml

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, phpunit

I am trying to use phpunit through the CLI in order to migrate from Netbeans to Sublime Text.
I have the weirdest issue when giving phpunit the path to the phpunit.xml file : it only accepts absolute path et refuses any relative path.
Any relative path given to the phpunit.xml file leads to this error :

> Could not read "phpunit.xml"

Example :

```
Maximes-MacBook-Pro:Frontoffice mbritto$ pwd
/Users/mbritto/Documents/Frontoffice
Maximes-MacBook-Pro:Frontoffice mbritto$ phpunit -c phpunit.xml
Could not read "phpunit.xml".
```

The phpunit.xml is present in this folder and is readable by my user.
It actually works if I don't give the path to the file :

```
Maximes-MacBook-Pro:Frontoffice mbritto$ phpunit
PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /Users/mbritto/Documents/Frontoffice/phpunit.xml

#Preparing Application Unit Tests
.^C
```

Or if I give the absolute path to the file :

```
Maximes-MacBook-Pro:Frontoffice mbritto$ phpunit -c /Users/mbritto/Documents/Frontoffice/phpunit.xml
PHPUnit 3.7.28 by Sebastian Bergmann.

Configuration read from /Users/mbritto/Documents/Frontoffice/phpunit.xml

#Preparing Application Unit Tests
..^C
```

I need this in order to use the phpunit plugin in Sublime Text which gives the phpunit.xml file to the command line with the path to the file to test.

My config :

- OSX 10.9.1
- PHP 5.4.24 (via brew)
- PHPUnit 3.7.28 (via brew) (also tested with a phar)

Any idea why it would do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out what was wrong with my tests; in my bootstrap.php file I was doing this :

```
chdir(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../src/");
```

So that classes and autoload would find actual classes that are separated from my test classes.
If I remove this line, the tests crashes because it can't find my classes but at least my tests are executed.
I'll work on the include path rather than changing directory so my tests will be working again.

Comment: I have a bootstrap file in the root of my project, so when I launch PHPUnit, I am in the directory I want to be in (top of the tree) similar to when I run the application, so everything can be found.  My normal includes/requires then always use relative pathing as they know where they are in the application (lib is under app, and DB under lib, so the app includes lib/DB).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, my src and my tests folders are siblings and on my server the src folder is the root of my project. That is why I needed to execute the tests as if I were in the src folder in order to include files but also to be able to load resources (images, etc.). I finally ended up modifying the include path in the bootstrap file and modified my pages so they access resources relatively from their position instead of from the root of the project.